# $P(a,b,c)=P(bc,ca,ab)$ weighted projective planes for pairwise coprime $a,b,c$

Tags: complex-geometry, group-actions, quotient-spaces, projective-space, orbifolds

Let $a,b,c\geq 2$ be pairwise coprime integers. The (complex) weighted projective plane $P(a,b,c)$ is the quotient of $\Bbb C^3-\{0\}$ by the action of $\Bbb C^*=\Bbb C-\{0\}$ given by $t\cdot (x,y,z)=(t^ax,t^by,t^cz)$. Or equivalently, the quotient of $S^5\subset \Bbb C^3$ by the $S^1$-action given by $t\cdot (x,y,z)=(t^ax,t^by,t^cz)$. (For example, p.3 in [https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~mabreu/preprints/weighted.pdf](https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/%7Emabreu/preprints/weighted.pdf))  On the other hand, according to p.6, Example 7 of https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/pamq/2008/0004/0002/PAMQ-2008-0004-0002-a001.pdf, $P(a,b,c)$ is the quotient of $S^5$ by the $S^1$-action given by $t\cdot (x,y,z)=(t^{bc}x,t^{ca}y,t^{ab}z)$. If this is true then it means that $P(a,b,c)=P(bc,ca,ab)$, but I can't see why. How can we show that these two are homeomorphic?

Comment: Orbitwise, atleast, I understand what's happening. Let $ X = \mathbb{C}^3 - 0 $ and $ G $ the multiplicative group. Then $ X $ has a stratification $ X = X^0 \sqcup X^1 \sqcup X^2 $ where $ X^i $ is the subset with exactly $ i $ entries equal to zero. The orbits $ X^2/G $ are three points in both cases and the orbits $ X^1/G $ are three copies of the projective line. Finally, clearly the map on $ X^0 $ given by $ (x,y,z) \rightarrow (yz,zx,xy) $ descends to the respective quotients, so these orbits are also in bijection.

Comment: I need to think more about the structure of the quotient as a complex variety with singular points, I recall that toric geometry can help here.